# Best practice for scehduled background task Android

Tags: android, service, timer, background, scheduled-tasks

I am creating a notification app, which will alert user after they set a reminder notification. My current implementation logic is:

1. Create a Service, which starts running in background when user opens their app.
2. In onCreate() method of service, I am implementing a Timer task which will repeat after 5000ms interval and will call a method, which will check all reminders set by user and notify user if any reminder is set for current time.
3. I use broadcast receiver  to run the service on Boot_Completed event, if in case user turns off their phone.

This implementation is working good, I have faced no issues with it, but my concern is that is this a good practice? Keeping in mind that service running and checking every 5 secs will consume battery. Also if user turns on Stamina Mode, Power saving mode or any such mode, will OS kill my service. Is there anything I can do to give priority to my Service not to be killed.

If there is any other more efficient way to implement this sort of task, I want to implement that in my project.

Looking forward for suggestions.

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best approach is wakeful intent service with alarm receiver as mentioned here

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Answer (score 0):

all good but use `AlarmManager.setRepeating()` as timer. the intent come even if your app killed.